# Terraform module output reference

Tags: module, terraform

I have two modules in two different folders

-modules

- vpc

  - vpc.tf
- asg

  - asg.tf

1. VPC
2. ASG (Auto scaling group)

i want to refer the public_subnets from VPC module in ASG module. to be precise.
i am unable to read the value of the below line in asg.tf

vpc_zone_identifier       =   ***module.vpc.public_subnets***

## vpc.tf

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  name                             = "${var.namespace}-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs             = ["eu-central-1a", "eu-central-1b", "eu-central-1c"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}

# asg.tf
module "asg" {
   source  = "terraform-aws-modules/autoscaling/aws"
   version = "~> 4.0" 
   name                             = "${var.namespace}-ASG"
   min_size                  = 2
   max_size                  = 5
   desired_capacity          = 2
   wait_for_capacity_timeout = 0
   health_check_type         = "ELB"
   vpc_zone_identifier       =   module.vpc.public_subnets
   lt_name                = "${var.namespace}-LT"
   description            = "Launch template example"
   update_default_version = true
   key_name = "frankfurt"
   #security_groups = [module.ec2_security_group.this_security_group_id]
   use_lt    = true
   create_lt = true
   image_id          = "ami-090717c950a5c34d3"
   instance_type     = "t2.micro"
   create_lc = true
   user_data = "${file("./userdata.sh")}"
}
```

i know i have to use output variables & values to access the above. but, need some helping hand.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how your module is working.
Create an `outputs.tf` in the `vpc/` dir and add:

```
output "public_subnets" {
  value       = [aws_subnet.subnet_1a_public.id, aws_subnet.subnet_1b_public.id] 
  description = "List of public subnets"
}
```

The `value` depends on how you are creating your subnets and naming them. But I would think something like `aws_subnet.some-name-you-chose.id`

Next you can use the subnets indeed like you did:

```
vpc_zone_identifier       =   module.vpc.public_subnets
```